# Extract array from custom field

Tags: custom-field, array, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using woocommerce product bundles extension.
I need to manipulate some informations about bundled post.
Actually I found the bundled product container has a hidden custom field named _bundled_ids which in the database has this value a:3:{i:0;i:105;i:1;i:80;i:2;i:70;}

For what I understand this value is the list of the ids of the products bundled.

How can I extract this infos in a comma separated list of ids (i.e. 105,80,70)?

I have tried with get_custom_post_meta() but everything I can get is ARRAY.

Hope you can help.
Best regards and thanks

Carlo

EDIT

As I already stated I need to get the data stored in this custom field as a comma separated list of numbers.

I tried to create a shortcode with this code inside my functions.php file:

```
add_shortcode('bundled_ids','bundled_ids_func');
function bundled_ids_func() {    
    $meta_values = get_post_meta( $post->ID , '_bundled_ids' );    
    $mydata = unserialize($meta_values);

    return $mydata;
}
```

But I get nothing

EDIT 2

```
add_shortcode('bundled_ids','bundled_ids_func');
function bundled_ids_func() {
    $meta_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , '_bundled_ids', true );
    $id_list = print_r($meta_values, true);

    return $id_list;
}
```

with this code I get this result:

Array ( [0] => 105 [1] => 80 [2] => 70 )

Comment: That is a serialized array, which is why you get an array when you use `get_custom_meta`. That function will unserialize if needed. It is unclear what you are asking. Please try to clarify.

Comment: Hi @s_ha_dum, thanks for your comment. I'm trying to get a list of values stored in the array separated by comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly pure PHP, but you need to [`implode`](https://www.php.net/function.implode) the array.

```
add_shortcode('bundled_ids','bundled_ids_func');
function bundled_ids_func() {    
    $meta_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , '_bundled_ids', true );  
    if (!empty($meta_values)) {
      $mydata = implode(',',$meta_values); // add this line
      return $mydata;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @s_ha_dum with this code I get nothing. :(

Comment: Sorry, you need the third parameter for `get_post_meta` set to `true`.

Comment: Even setting the third parameter to true I get nothing. Maybe setting a foreach could help?

Comment: @Carletto0282 : see the edit. That is what I get for trying to post code without running it.

Comment: Great man! thank you very much! I was trying something like `add_shortcode('bundled_ids','bundled_ids_func');
function bundled_ids_func() {
 $meta_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , '_bundled_ids', true );
 
 foreach ($meta_values as $key => $value) {
  $ids .= $value.', ';
 }

 return $ids;
}` but yuor code is far way better! Thanks again